# Cosmos DB query is very slow for large dataset, why?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

We have a requirement to retrieve all messages for a given client to a portal grid.
Our largest client would have roughly 40k - 50k messages returned for the maximum period of 12 months.

Our container partition key is the **account ID**, and this is what we are filtering on.

**Our code:**

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<MessageEntity>> GetItemsAsync(string accountId)
    {
        var query = $"SELECT c.Property1, c.Property2, c.Property3, c.Property4, c.Property5, c.Property6, c.Property7 FROM c WHERE c.accountId = '{accountId}'";
        
        return await RunQuery(query);
    }
    
    private async Task<List<MessageEntity>> RunQuery(string query)
    {
        var iterator = Container.GetItemQueryIterator<MessageEntity>(new QueryDefinition(query), requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions() { MaxItemCount = -1, PopulateIndexMetrics = true });
        var results = new List<MessageEntity>();
        while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
        {
            var response = await iterator.ReadNextAsync();
            results.AddRange(response.ToList());
        }
        return results;
    }
```

The full dataset is around 45mb and takes around 60 seconds to complete.

**Question**

Have we missed something from our usage of the SDK, is there something obviously inneficient about the way we are doing this, or are we fundamentally using cosmos db incorrectly if we are attempting to pull back this amount of data.

Comment: is accountid the partition key and why you are not going with pagination>

Comment: It is, and I dont get to pick the technical approach

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/tips-tricks-query-pagination/

Answer (score 0):

The first important point is `PopulateIndexMetrics`. Based on the API documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.queryrequestoptions.populateindexmetrics?view=azure-dotnet

"Please note that this options will incur overhead, so it should be enabled only when debugging slow queries."

This should not be enabled permanently. Assuming you already obtained the information from the response to improve your indexes, you should turn it off / not enable it.

The second part really depends on where the latency is coming from. This could be network latency but there is no extra information. I would recommend taking a look at: https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-dot-net-sdk-slow-request

Particularly:

- Where is the location of the App compared with the region you are reading data from. If the account has multiple regions, are you setting CosmosClientOptions.ApplicationPreferredRegions or ApplicationRegion to make sure you are reading from the closest region?
- Are you measuring the latency across a period of time or a single operation? Are you taking into consideration the [cold start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/sdk-connection-modes#routing)?
- If you capture the Diagnostics, do you see the time spent on Transit Time? If yes, that is related to network latency and data transfer.